# MySQL using select statement in update sets null

Tags: mysql, select, nested, sql-update

I am trying to update a tree in the way I describe. I have a tree of depth 5 and the leaf nodes have values greater than 0. Now for each parent, I want to calculate most visited value in the children and set that value for itself. By now I am trying to do that this way:

```
update itmanagement.PRC_processes parent
set MainStructID = (case when (select MainStructID
from (select * from itmanagement.PRC_processes) child
where parent.ProcessID = child.ParentID
group by MainStructID
order by count(*)
limit 1) is null then 0 else (select MainStructID
from (select * from itmanagement.PRC_processes) child
where parent.ProcessID = child.ParentID
group by MainStructID
order by count(*)
limit 1) end),
SubStructID = (case when (select SubStructID
from (select * from itmanagement.PRC_processes) child
where parent.ProcessID = child.ParentID
group by SubStructID
order by count(*)
limit 1) is null then 0 else (select SubStructID
from (select * from itmanagement.PRC_processes) child
where parent.ProcessID = child.ParentID
group by SubStructID
order by count(*)
limit 1) end)
where ProcessID > 0 and MainStructID = 0 and SubStructID = 0;
```

But after running the above query, nothing changes. For example the row with id of ProcessID = 24 keeps previous values of 0. But the query below returns value:

```
select SubStructID
from (select * from itmanagement.PRC_processes) child
where child.ParentID = 24
group by SubStructID
order by count(*)
limit 1;
```

My own guess is that the select statement returns a table (also with only one row) and it does not work in assignment.

So what is the problem and how to fix that?

Comment: You will need to add some sample data and the table descriptions, e.g. as an sql fiddle. Most likely problem: are the current values for `MainStructID` and `SubStructId` really both `0` or maybe (at least one of them) `null` (in which case your query will not update because of the `where`-condition)? Also, you probably need `order by count(*) desc` instead of `order by count(*)`. Unrelated: you can use `set MainStructID = coalesce(...,0)` instead of `set MainStructID = case when ... is null then 0 else ... end` (it does not affect your problem though, just makes your code shorter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally changed query to work in some other way.
And also I have made use of @Solarflare's answer to make it more efficient.

Now the query is like below. I hope It helps others:

```
update itmanagement.PRC_processes parent
join (select child.ParentID ParentID
, (select MainStructID from itmanagement.PRC_processes childer where childer.ParentID = child.ParentID group by MainStructID order by count(*) desc LIMIT 1) maxSeenMainStructID
, (select SubStructID from itmanagement.PRC_processes childer where childer.ParentID = child.ParentID group by SubStructID order by count(*) desc LIMIT 1) maxSeenSubStructID
from itmanagement.PRC_processes child
where child.ParentID is not null
group by child.ParentID) calcProcesses on parent.ProcessID = calcProcesses.ParentID
set parent.MainStructID = coalesce(calcProcesses.maxSeenMainStructID, 0)
,parent.SubStructID = coalesce(calcProcesses.maxSeenSubStructID, 0)
where parent.ProcessID > 0 and parent.MainStructID = 0 and parent.SubStructID = 0;
```

Now everything just goes fine.

Comment: (Aside: you are welcome to 'self accept' this answer by clicking on the tick mark, to say that it is solved.)